# Is there any other way of using Webgrid than using IEnumerable<xxx.models.modelname> in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, webgrid

I have to store data in the models as well as display from different model on the View in Webgrid.
I want to use `@model projectname.models.modelname` for storing the data in my modelname
and I also want to display data from another model(s) in Webgrid in the same view so i will have to use `@model IEnumerable<projectname.Models.newmodel>`

How can I use multiple models in same view and that too of IEnumerable..?

Is there any option which I can use..

I am new to MVC so please anyone can help me out..

Comment: Is there any option to change the source of webgrid to IEnumerable instead of Model

Answer (score 0):

You can create another class file like common.cs and in that you have to create public class and create members like

```
Public Class Employee
        Public EmpNo As Integer
        Public Designation As String
        Public Address As String
        Public Date_Of_Birth As DateTime
End Class
```

and you can access it by implement that common class file in the controller and use it by creating the object of the Employee class like

```
Employee e
e.EmpNo
e.Designation
e.Address
e.Date_Of_Birth
```

and set those values.

Now you have to use it in view so you can access these values directly in view:

```
@Models.Common.UserName
```

Here i declared Models because my common file is in Models that's why.

Comment: May be this link has your solution look into this     https://pavanarya.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/displaying-data-in-a-grid-using-webgrid-in-cshtml/ or may be this one http://forums.asp.net/t/1819855.aspx?adding+columns+to+IEnumerable+WebGridColumn+for+WebGrid